# Why did the Imam hold a sword in Hagia Sophia while giving the sermon?

Tags: khutbah

[image]

Is there any Islamic basis for doing that?

Comment: I have heard it was an Ottoman tradition to give khutbah with swords in places they conquered. I don't know any evidence for that. You might have to ask in history.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TheZ But does the tradition have any Islamic teachings behind it or is it purely cultural? I have seen Imams holding a staff in other places.

Comment: There certainly is a backup and Islamic evidence for this act. But in the given case one can't deny or exclude a political background. As the Hagia Sophia already has been turned to a mosque by the 'Othman's but Atatürk turned it into a museum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the majority of the mahabs, leaning on either a staff, bow or sword in the Khutbah is sunnah and hence mustahab.

> يسن أن يعتمد على قوس أو سيف أو عصا أو نحوها
>
> The Sunnah is to lean on a bow or sword or staff or like that
>
> <sup>— [مجموع شرح المهذب](https://shamela.ws/book/2186/2185)</sup>

The evidence in hadith includes:

> شهدنا فيها الجمعة مع رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقام متوكئا على عصا أو قوس
>
> We offered the Friday prayer along with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). He stood leaning on a staff or a bow.
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/707)</sup>

According to the Hanafi madhab leaning on a sword is desirable in areas conquered by force.

> يخطب الإمام بسيف في بلدة فتحت به كمكة وإلا لا كالمدينة
>
> The Imam will deliever the sermon with a sword in a city conquered by it such as Mecca and otherwise not  such as Medinah
>
> <sup>— [الدر المختار](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/819#p1)</sup>